# Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'unprefixed' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                    11:53:50
error  in ./node_modules/vue2-datepicker/index.css

Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'unprefixed' of undefined

@ ./node_modules/vue2-datepicker/index.css 4:14-131 15:3-20:5 16:22-139
@ ./src/main.js
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://10.250.1.202:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

I don't understand what to do

Comment: Please provide a more complete exmaple with some code